# Blank page whenever I assign an array with 2k entries

Tags: php, smarty

I am using Smarty Template Engine. In my website I load entries from my database to create markers on a google map. Everything was working ok when I had ~20 entries in my array.

But now that I have a query with 2k results, it looks like Smarty can not handle it. I get a completely blank page. Error reporting does not show any error related to Smarty, only PHP notices.

I do not have access to my server's php errors log.

Any idea?

Comment: It is hard to have ideas when we have no idea what the query or template looks like...

Comment: `register_shutdown_function(function(){ print_r(error_get_last()); while((ob_get_level())) print ob_get_clean(); });`, maybe you got more than a blank screen.

Comment: Or try `ini_set("memory_limit","2G");` or more if more memory installed.